# Please don't re-render MathJax after every key press; only do it if I have edited an equation

Tags: feature-request, latex

On TeX-enabled sites, pressing any character in the question/answer box re-renders all TeX equations. I have found this to be incredibly inconvenient. In posts with long answers, I have found that there is a *significant* delay between when I pressed a key and when the output is rendered. Typing becomes something of a pain due to this lag, especially when trying to accurately use the backspace key.

On slower computers, the lag grows worse rapidly. A workaround I frequently have to use is typing my entire post into Notepad/Gedit, pasting it over.

Would it be possible to reconfigure the preview script to only re-render MathJax if a character was changed in a MathJax equation?

Comment: Surely this belongs on the meta of the site this happens on?

Comment: @Oded This happens on all TeX-enabled sites. It's a problem with the preview script as a whole.

Comment: Is this even possible for the SE team to change something about that?

Comment: [If only there were something faster and more standard that didn’t require JavaScript and caused little additional load…](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152430)

Comment: @Jan Probably. I don't know how the preview script works, but it should be possible. Unless there's something weird I don't know about.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/suggestion-for-changing-latex-preview-compile-frequency

Comment: [Really, though, it’s instant](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/MathML_Project/MathML_Torture_Test$samples/MathML_Torture_Test?revision=484295)

Comment: And this - TeX incremental preview: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/a-prototype-for-incremental-preview-updates